Contest Problem - Stanford Math Tournament 2024
I was trying to solve the problem from Stanford's math tournament and wonder if you could opine what is wrong in my approach: Problem No 13
https://www.stanfordmathtournament.com/pdfs/smt2024/team-solutions.pdf
The problem is
Two parabolas $ = ( − 1)^2 + $ and $ = ( − 1)^
2 + $ intersect at a single point, where  and  are
non-negative real numbers. Let  and  denote the minimum and maximum possible values of  +
, respectively. Compute ⌊⌋ + d
Here is how I solve with calculus and geometry
Transform the equations to $(y-1) = (x-1)^2 + a-1$
and
$(x-1) = (y-1)^2 + b-1$
Let the point of interesection be $(x_1, y_1)$.
Now let $u = x_1-1$
and $v = y_1 -1$
For it to intersect at only one point, it is also true that the two parabolas are tangent at $(x_1, y_1)$.
Now $m_1 = \frac{dy}{dx} = 2(x-1)$
and $m_2 = \frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2(y-1)}$
$m_1 = m_2$
Thus $(x-1)(y-1) = \frac{1}{4}$
At $(x_1,y_1), (x_1-1)(y_1-1) = \frac{1}{4}$
In terms of u and v
You have $v = u^2+a-1$
and $u = v^2+b-1$
Now adding the two $u+v = u^2+v^2 +a+b-2$
Now, it should meet the criterion $uv=\frac{1}{4}$
Now use Lagrange Multiplier
where $a+b = 2 +u+v-u^2-v^2$
Let the $f(u,v) = a+b = 2+u+v-u^2-v^2$
and $g(u,v) = uv = \frac{1}{4}$
$\frac{\delta f}{\delta x} + \lambda\frac{\delta g}{\delta x} = 0$
$\frac{\delta f}{\delta y} + \lambda\frac{\delta g}{\delta y} = 0$
$\lambda = \frac{(2u-1)}{v}$
$\lambda = \frac{(2v-1)}{u}$
Solving both $2(u^2-v^2) = (u-v)$
So $u = v$ or $(u+v = 2)$
Put $u = v$ in $u^2 = \frac{1}{4}$
Thus $u = v = \frac{1}{2} $ or $u = v = -\frac{1}{2} $
$u+v = 2$ gives non real solutions and hence ignored
Now Maximum of $f(u,v) = 2 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}$
Thus Maximum of (a+b) $= \frac{5}{2}$
Now Minimum of $f(u,v) = 2 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}$
Thus Minimum of (a+b) $= \frac{1}{2}$
The solution is extracted to be $\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{2}}\right\rfloor + \frac{5}{2} = \boxed{\frac{5}{2}}$
It differs from the Stanford's solution, could someone tell me what is wrong and see if there could be an issue in their solution because the last paragraph where the two curves are supposed to tangent does not happen for (2,1).
For negative u, v, it is tangential satisfying the criterion but it also intersects in one other point.
Hence the solution for Min goes
Thus for some value of u and v where $ (u+v = u^2 + v^2)$
Now Minimum of $f(u,v) = 2 $
and hence The solution is extracted to be $\left\lfloor{{2}}\right\rfloor + \frac{5}{2} = \boxed{\frac{9}{2}}$


I stoped reading when I came to:"These two parabolas are symmetrical to y and x axis respectively" which is not true.

I will remove it and see if you can opine on that

If u, v are negative, there are 3 intersections

@Eric, I have just added a graph and it intersects at two points.  Thanks for pointing it out

The issue arises from the fact that there are some more bounds on $u$ and $v$. It is not sufficient that there is just a point of tangency of the parabolas, this point must be the only intersection. This is hard to rigorously put into boundaries, but a key point to note is that the intersection must be a point $(x_i,y_i)$ where $x_i, y_i \geq 1$. In order for the parabolas to only intersect at one point, the intersection point must be on the "right half" of the $y=(x-1)^2 + a$ parabola and the "upper half" of the $x = (y-1)^2 + b$ parabola. You can easily prove this by contradiction: If the intersection is on the "left half" of the vertical parabola, then there must be another point where they intersect on the "right half". Again, this is not rigorous, but as long as you can visualize why this is the case, we can state $x_i, y_i \geq 1$. Note that this is not the strictest bounds possible since this case still results in some double intersections.
However, this is a sufficient bound to answer the problem correctly. Converting to $u$ and $v$ we get $u, v \geq 0$. We can rewrite $f(u,v) = a + b = \frac{5}{2} - (v-\frac{1}{2})^2- (u-\frac{1}{2})^2$. Now using our additional restrictions that $u$ and $v$ must be positive results in a minimum of at least $f(u,v)=2$. Remember that $u=v=0$ is not actually possible but will be lower than the true minimum. Since we only care for the $\lfloor $min$(f(u,v))\rfloor$, $2$ will suffice.
